# Unable to play Sacred 2 Multiplayer

Tags: pc, technical-issues, sacred-2

I purchased Sacred 2 from GoGamer.com.  I was able to successfully install the game and even to authenticate my key. However, when I tried to make a multiplayer account, I was informed that my key was invalid.

I filed a ticket with CDV (the NA publisher), but haven't heard anything.

Anybody know if there is a workaround of some kind? Or has had success with CDV?

Comment: I've had a similar error trying to play Sacred Gold off of Steam.  Works fine for singleplayer, but unconnectable on multiplayer either online or over LAN.

Answer (score 1):

This question has been sitting a while so I'll throw it out there, but did Sacred 2 use any corporate servers for multiplayer matchmaking or account tracking?  Maybe they turned off said servers.

Answer (score 0):

I just bought the game today.  Been waiting for the price to drop.  Can't play multiplayer because it tells me the key is invalid.  I bought it in a store, and I have the box.  It seems like they stopped supporting the multiplayer aspect of the game a while back.  Or at least that is what I gather from the hundreds of forum posts that claim sacred 2 support team won't respond.  CDV got their money and they are moving on.  To hell with the customers I guess.  I am giving this game a 1.0 on gamespot and other site just because CDV won't acknowledge us.

Comment: Well, it doesn't really matter now.  I played a few hours today on the toughest difficulty and the game is extremely easy and boring.  I think I will be looking for another game.